# How can I improve the conciseness of my Lua wrapper functions?

Tags: c++, lua, variadic-templates

I have the following template specializations which wrap C++ functions to Lua:

```
  template<class ...Args>
  struct Wrapper<void (*)(Args...)> {

    using F = void (*)(Args...);

    static int f (lua_State *L)
    {
      Lua lua(L);

      // Grab the function pointer.
      F f = (F) lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));

      // Build a tuple of arguments.
      auto args = lua.CheckArgs<1, Args...>();

      // Apply the function to the tuple.
      FunctionPointer<F> fp(f);
      fp.Apply(args);

      return 0;

    }
  };

  template<class R, class ...Args>
  struct Wrapper<R (*)(Args...)> {

    using F = R (*)(Args...);

    static int f (lua_State *L)
    {
      Lua lua(L);

      // Grab the function pointer.
      F f = (F) lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));

      // Build a tuple of arguments.
      auto args = lua.CheckArgs<1, Args...>();

      // Apply the function to the tuple.
      FunctionPointer<F> fp(f);
      lua.Push( fp.Apply(args) );

      return 1;

    }
  };
```

Notice how they differ rather minimally. In the first specialization, `FunctionPointer<F>::Apply` returns void. In the second, it's result is pushed onto the Lua stack.

*Can I combine these two specializations into one?*

I realize this may seem pedantic, but I have had to write a lot of these wrappers elsewhere in my code, because of variations in the type of the function being wrapper (free function, or PMF, const or not). I have a total of 14 such specializations.

Here are two more which differ only by whether the PMF is const or not:

```
  template <typename Self, typename ...Args>
  struct MethodWrapper<void (Self::*)(Args...) >
  {
    using F = void (Self::*)(Args...);

    static int f (lua_State *L)
    {
      Lua lua(L);

      F f = *(F *)lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
      Self* self = lua.CheckPtr<Self>(1);

      auto args = lua.CheckArgs<2, Args...>();

      FunctionPointer<F> fp(f);
      try {
        fp.Apply(self, args);
      } catch(std::exception& e) {
        luaL_error(L, e.what());
      }

      return 0;
    }
  };

  template <typename R, typename Self, typename ...Args>
  struct MethodWrapper<R (Self::*)(Args...) const >
  {
    // exactly the same as above
  };
```

*Can I avoid this cut and paste?* (Without using macros though)

Related, but suffers from the same number of required specializations: [How to use variadic templates to make a generic Lua function wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590471/how-to-use-variadic-templates-to-make-a-generic-lua-function-wrapper)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make a generic functor which takes `fp`, `args`, and `lua`, and calls `lua.Push()`, with a partial specialization for when `R` is `void` which just invokes the function and ignores the (void) result.  You would then invoke it like this:

```
ApplyAndPushIfNotVoid<R>()(lua, fp, args);
```

Comment: Maybe you could make the PMF const and non-const versions be thin wrappers around a completely generic `typename T` implementation which doesn't mention their signature?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to eliminate all that repetitive template specialization. In fact, for a one-off branching case, like in your free-function `struct Wrapper`, you don't even need to write a specialization to hide it -- just use `std::is_void` from `type_traits`:

```
template<typename R, typename ...Args>
struct Wrapper
{
  using F = R (*)(Args...);

  static int f (lua_State *L, F f)
  {
    // ...
    FunctionPointer<F> fp {f};
    if (std::is_void<R>::value)
    {
      fp.Apply(args);
      return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      lua.Push( fp.Apply(args) );
      return 1;
    }
  }
};
```

The compiler will optimize out one of the branches depending on how it gets instantiated.

There is a slight wrinkle though, when the return type is `R = void` the falsey branch still gets type-checked during instantiation which results in the body being ill-formed.

Using template specialization like in the other answer is one obvious solution. There is an alternative workaround: have `FunctionPointer<F>::Apply` return a dummy `void_type` when `R = void`. For example using `std::conditional`, `FunctionPointer` can be modified to work like:

```
template <typename F>
class FunctionPointer
{
  template <typename R, typename ...Args>
  static R func_return( R(*)(Args...) )
  { return {}; }
  using R_ = decltype( func_return( (F)nullptr ) );
  struct void_type {};

public:
  F f;
  using R = typename std::conditional<std::is_void<R_>::value,
                                      void_type, R_>::type;
  template <typename ...Args>
  R Apply(std::tuple<Args...> &args)
  { 
    // ...
    return {};
  }
};
```

[**IDEone Demo**](http://ideone.com/F9lL4k) with external dependent types stubbed out.

For the `MethodWrapper`, I would identify the different 'traits' and aspects it needs from the member pointer and extract all those and hide it behind some trait class. Let's call it `PMF_traits`:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct PMF_traits
{
private:
  using T_traits = decltype( PMF_trait_helper( (T)nullptr ) );
public:
  using class_type  = typename T_traits::class_type;
  using return_type = typename T_traits::return_type;
  static const bool const_member = T_traits::const_member;
  using type = T;
};
```

The `PMF_trait_helper` itself is just an empty function to help deduce and extract type information out of `PMF`. Here is where the `const` and `non-const` `PMF` is handled. That information is captured using `PMF_trait_detail` and passed back up to `PMF_traits`.

```
template <typename R, typename Class, bool Is_Const>
struct PMF_trait_detail
{
  using class_type = Class;
  using return_type = R;
  static const bool const_member = Is_Const;
};

template <typename R, typename Class, typename ...Args>
PMF_trait_detail<R, Class, false> PMF_trait_helper( R (Class::*)(Args...) )
{ return PMF_trait_detail<R, Class, false> (); }
template <typename R, typename Class, typename ...Args>
PMF_trait_detail<R, Class, false> PMF_trait_helper( R (Class::*)(Args...) const)
{ return PMF_trait_detail<R, Class, true> (); }
```

With that setup `MethodWrapper` no longer needs to handle `const` `non-const` cases separately

```
template <typename PMF, typename ...Args>
struct MethodWrapper
{
  typedef typename PMF_traits<PMF>::class_type Self;

  int f (lua_State *L)
  {
    // ...
    FunctionPointer<PMF> fp { (PMF) lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)) };
    Self *self = lua.CheckPtr<Self>(1);
    // ...
    try
    {
      // Almost like 'Wrapper' above
      // handle void and non-void case etc.
      if (std::is_void< typename PMF_traits<PMF>::return_type >::value)
      {
        fp.Apply(self, args);
        return 0;
      }
      else { // ... }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
      return luaL_error(L, e.what());
    }
  }
};
```

Note I didn't capture the variadic arguments in the `PMF_traits` just to keep the template complexity and syntactic verbiage down but it should be possible to encode and save this info too using `std::tuple` if you need that.

Using this technique you should be able to refactor and significantly reduce the number of specializations you need.

Comment: I tried your if (std::is_void<R>::value) suggestion and it didn't compile because the else branch is still type-checked even when value is true. "No matching member function for call to 'Push'."

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for not testing it more thoroughly. After some thinking, this is still workable. What you have to do is make `fp.Apply` return a dummy `void_type` when `R = void` so the instantiated body isn't ill-formed. John's method might be more straight-forward at this point using just specialization.

Comment: @Taylor I've added the workaround I mentioned in my comment. See if that helps with the compile error.