# C++11: Parameter Pack Expansion Counter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, parameter-passing

I'd like to increment a counter for each parameter during parameter pack expansion.
Here is some pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```
    template<class ... Args>
    void doSomething(Args ... _args)
    {
        std::size_t counter = 0;
        bar(doSomethingWithOneArg(_args, counter++)...);
    }
```

The problem with this code is, that while the order of the `Args`is preserved, the order in which the function parameters are evaluated is not defined, i.e. on `clang` the order in which the counter expressions are evaluated is the same as the order of `Args` while in `gcc` it is reversed. What is a portable, standard way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Usual comment: why do you want this?

Comment: I think this question I asked a while back might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006450/63791

Comment: @GManNickG I am writing some Lua binding code at the moment and want to generate lua stack indices on the fly.

Comment: @Alex very relevant link indeed, thanks!

Comment: Here's my library with the code that uses the stuff I got from those answers: https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapper/src/fd9c4fdbf4b25034e3b8475a2c8da66b7caab427/luawrapperutil.hpp?fileviewer=file-view-default#luawrapperutil.hpp-619

Comment: @Alex great, I actually checked it out a while back, looks solid and helped me a lot to figure some things out. Ended up writing my own for reasons of error and memory management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a helper function:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void doSomething(Args &&... args)
{
    doSomethingImpl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>(),
                    std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename ...Args, std::size_t ...N>
void doSomethingImpl(std::index_sequence<N...>, Args &&... args)
{
    bar(oneCommand(std::forward<Args>(args), N)...);
}
```

Comment: great, didn't know about `std:: make_index_sequence`, thanks for the demo, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I accepted this as the answer. The only thing I changed is to use my own implementation of index_sequence as that is not available in c++11.

Comment: @moka: Thanks! Yes, anything that houses a pack of integers will do. The "make" part is the most tedious to have to reinvent yourself.

Comment: The "order in which the function parameters are evaluated " is still implementation defined.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Yeah, but now we don't care. The ordering was only a problem in the OP's code because it prevented her from computing consistent counter values. In my code, I don't need to compute those values, because I simply extract them from the pack.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the order of evaluation to be in line with the order of the arguments for `doSomething` you can expand the arguments into an initializer:

```
template <typename ...Args, std::size_t ...N>
void doSomethingImpl(std::index_sequence<N...>, 
  std::tuple<Args...> && args)
{
  using std::get;
  int t_[] = { 0, (static_cast<void>(oneCommand(
    get<N>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), N)), 0)... };
  static_cast<void>(t_); // "use" t_ to silence warnings 
}

template <typename ...Args>
void doSomething(Args &&... args)
{
  doSomethingImpl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>(),
    std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Why the C-style cast ... :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB: A possibly suboptimal habit to cast discarded expressions/return values to void using the c-style cast notation.

Answer (score 1):

You might utilize list-initializatio in conjunction with a comma operator to sequence the function calls:

```
template<class T>
void doSomethingWithOneArg(const T&, std::size_t counter)
{
    std::cout << counter << ": " << typeid(T).name() << '\n';
}

template<class ... Args>
void doSomething(Args ... args)
{
    std::size_t counter = 0;
    std::initializer_list<int>{ ( doSomethingWithOneArg(args, counter++), 0) ... };
}

int main() {
    doSomething(char(0), int(0), long(0));
}
```

*8.5.4 List-initialization (N4296)*

> *4*
>   Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is,
>   every value computation and side effect associated with a given
>   initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in
>   the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.